oauth post request is not working and getting signature invalid error
OAuth post request is not working and getting a signature invalid error.
I'm trying to create a Magento provider for airflow.
from __future__ import annotations

import base64

import hashlib

import hmac

import time

import urllib.parse

import uuid

from urllib.parse import urlencode

import requests
from airflow.exceptions import AirflowException

from airflow.hooks.base import BaseHook

class MagentoHook(BaseHook):

    conn_name_attr = "magento_conn_id"

    default_conn_name = "magento_default"

    conn_type = "magento"

    hook_name = "Magento"



    BASE_URL = "/rest/default/V1"  # Common base URL for Magento API



    def __init__(self, magento_conn_id=default_conn_name):

        super().__init__()

        self.magento_conn_id = magento_conn_id

        self.connection = self.get_connection(self.magento_conn_id)

        self._configure_oauth()



        # Validate connection host

        if not self.connection.host:

            raise AirflowException("Magento connection host is not set properly in Airflow connection")



    def _configure_oauth(self):    

        self.consumer_key = self.connection.extra_dejson.get("consumer_key")

        self.consumer_secret = self.connection.extra_dejson.get("consumer_secret")

        self.access_token = self.connection.extra_dejson.get("access_token")

        self.access_token_secret = self.connection.extra_dejson.get("access_token_secret")



        if not all([self.consumer_key, self.consumer_secret, self.access_token, self.access_token_secret]):

            raise AirflowException("Magento OAuth credentials are not set properly in Airflow connection")



    def _generate_oauth_parameters(self, url, method, data=None):

        """Generate OAuth parameters for the request."""

        oauth_nonce = str(uuid.uuid4())

        oauth_timestamp = str(int(time.time()))

        oauth_signature_method = "HMAC-SHA256"

        oauth_version = "1.0"



        # Parse the URL to separate the query parameters

        parsed_url = urllib.parse.urlparse(url)

        query_params = urllib.parse.parse_qsl(parsed_url.query)



        # Prepare OAuth parameters

        oauth_params = {

            "oauth_consumer_key": self.consumer_key,

            "oauth_nonce": oauth_nonce,

            "oauth_signature_method": oauth_signature_method,

            "oauth_timestamp": oauth_timestamp,

            "oauth_token": self.access_token,

            "oauth_version": oauth_version,

        }



        # Include data parameters if present

        if data:

            if method.upper() == "POST":

                # POST data should be included in the base string

                data_params = urlencode(data, doseq=True)               

                query_params.extend(urllib.parse.parse_qsl(data_params))



        # Combine OAuth and query/data parameters, and sort them

        all_params = oauth_params.copy()

        all_params.update(query_params)

        sorted_params = sorted(all_params.items(), key=lambda x: x[0])



        # Encode and create the parameter string

        #param_str = urllib.parse.urlencode(sorted_params, safe="")

        param_str = urlencode(sorted_params, quote_via=urllib.parse.quote)

        # Construct the base string

        #base_string = f"{method.upper()}&{urllib.parse.quote(parsed_url.scheme + '://' + parsed_url.netloc + parsed_url.path, safe='')}&{urllib.parse.quote(param_str, safe='')}"

        base_string = f"{method.upper()}&{urllib.parse.quote(parsed_url.scheme + '://' + parsed_url.netloc + parsed_url.path, safe='')}&{urllib.parse.quote(param_str, safe='')}"



        # Create the signing key

        signing_key = f"{urllib.parse.quote(self.consumer_secret, safe='')}&{urllib.parse.quote(self.access_token_secret, safe='')}"



        # Generate the OAuth signature

        oauth_signature = base64.b64encode(

            hmac.new(signing_key.encode(), base_string.encode(), hashlib.sha256).digest()

        ).decode()



        # Add the signature to OAuth parameters

        oauth_params["oauth_signature"] = oauth_signature



        # Construct the Authorization header

       

        auth_header = "OAuth " + ", ".join(
    [f'{urllib.parse.quote(k, safe="")}="{urllib.parse.quote(v, safe="")}"' for k, v in oauth_params.items()])
        return auth_header

    def _get_full_url(self, endpoint):

        """Construct the full URL for Magento API."""

        return f"https://{self.connection.host}{self.BASE_URL}/{endpoint}"



    def get_request(self, endpoint, search_criteria=None, method="GET", data=None):

        """Perform an API request to Magento."""

        if search_criteria:

            # Convert search criteria dictionary to URL parameters

            query_string = urlencode(search_criteria, doseq=True)

            endpoint = f"{endpoint}?{query_string}"

        url = self._get_full_url(endpoint)

        headers = {

            "Content-Type": "application/json",

            "Authorization": self._generate_oauth_parameters(url, method, data),

        }



        try:

            if method.upper() == "GET":

                response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False)

            else:

                response = requests.request(method, url, headers=headers, json=data)

            response.raise_for_status()  # Will raise an error for bad responses



        except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as http_err:

            error_details = None

            try:

                # Attempt to parse and log the error response

                error_details = response.json() if response.content else {}

                self.log.error("Error details: %s", error_details)

            except ValueError:

                # Failed to parse JSON response

                pass



            raise AirflowException(f"Request failed: {http_err}. Error details: {error_details}")



        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:

            raise AirflowException(f"Request failed: {str(e)}")



        return response.json()



    def post_request(self, endpoint, data=None):

        """Perform a POST API request to Magento."""

        url = self._get_full_url(endpoint)

        headers = {

            "Content-Type": "application/json",

            "Authorization": self._generate_oauth_parameters(url, "POST", data),

        }



        try:

            response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data, verify=False)

            response.raise_for_status()  # Will raise an error for bad responses



        except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as http_err:

            error_details = None

            try:

                # Attempt to parse and log the error response

                error_details = response.json() if response.content else {}

                self.log.error("Error details: %s", error_details)

            except ValueError:

                # Failed to parse JSON response

                pass



            raise AirflowException(f"Request failed: {http_err}. Error details: {error_details}")



        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:

            raise AirflowException(f"Request failed: {str(e)}")



        return response.json()


